# how do I take user input and pass it into a constructor in java? it says that artCourse is undefined

Tags: java, user-input

I can't figure out how to pass the users input... please help!?!? This is in java. My professor provided this i am to not make any changes to it.

```
 /** A generic course at a University
*/
public abstract class Course
{

  // The course subject
  private String subject;
  // The course number
  private int number;
  // The time the course meets
  private MeetingTime time;

  /** Create a new Course object and initialize the course
   * name, time and difficulty.
   * @param theSubject the course subject
   * @param theNumber the course number
   * @param theTime the course time
   */
 public Course (String theSubject, int theNumber,MeetingTime theTime)
{
   subject = theSubject;
   number = theNumber;
   // Store a copy of the time object in the course object.
   time = new MeetingTime (theTime.getStartTime(), theTime.getEndTime());
 }


  /** Get the time when the course meets.
    * @return the time the course meets
    */
  public MeetingTime getTime()
  {
   return new MeetingTime (time.getStartTime(), time.getEndTime());
  }
```

}

This is what I have so far for the main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> courseSchedule =new ArrayList<String>();
    String theSubject = "  ";
    Integer theNumber = 000;
    Double theTime = 0000.0;
    while (!theSubject.equals("DONE"))
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a course subject: ");
      theSubject = in.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter course number: ");
      theNumber = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter course start time and end time: ");
      theTime = in.nextDouble();
      String temp = in.nextLine();
      if (theSubject.equals("ART"))
      {
        System.out.print("Enter the studio number: ");
        String theStudioNumber = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the instructors name: ");
        String theInstructor = in.nextLine();
        ArtCourse artCourse = new ArtCourse (theSubject, theNumber, theTime, theStudioNumber, theInstructor);
      }
```

These are my sub class.

```
public class ArtCourse extends Course
{
  private String studioNumber;
  private String instructor;

  public ArtCourse (String theSubject, 
                    int theNumber, 
                    MeetingTime theTime, 
                    String theStudioNumber,
                    String theInstructor)
  {
   super(theSubject, theNumber, theTime);
   studioNumber = "????";
   instructor = "????";
  } 
}
```

Comment: You already have several lines of code where you create a new object and pass a parameter to the constructor. Why do you think this one instance of this task is different?

Comment: You need to create a subclass of Course first.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new Course in your main method. In your case, Course is abstract, which means it cannot be instantiated, but it can be subclassed. You could create a class, CourseImpl, that extends Course!

```
 public class CourseImpl extends Course {
      public CourseImpl(String subject, int courseNumber) {
            super( subject, courseNumber);
      }
 }
```

And then in your main method you can instantiate this implementation of Course.

```
 {
 ....
 theSubject = in.nextLine();
 ....
 Integer courseNumber = in.nextInt();
 CourseImpl aCourse = new CourseImpl (theSubject, courseNumber);
 }
```

Comment: Can you actually instantiate an abstract class like that?

Comment: Good point I was just going to ask if he actually meant abstract

Comment: Thank you for making corrections.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Course` class is `abstract`, for which you can't create an object.

If you shouldn't make any changes to the class file, then the answer is NO, because you can't instantiate the `Course` class.

But the other way to call the `Course` class constructor is through inheritance as shown below:

```
public class Course {
 //add your code
}

public class Maths extends Course {

  public Maths(String theSubject, int theNumber) {
        super(theSubject, theNumber);
  }
}
```

You can create the object using `Maths maths = new Maths(theSubject, courseNumber);` inside the `while` loop.

However, in your `while` loop string comparison is incorrect, strings should be compared with `.equals()` i.e., like `while(theSubject.equals("DONE"))`.

You can refer the below code:

```
while (!theSubject.equals("DONE")) {
  System.out.print("Enter a course subject: ");
  theSubject = in.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter course number: ");
  int courseNumber = in.nextInt();
  Maths maths = new Maths(theSubject, courseNumber);
}
```

Also, remember that `scanner.nextInt()` returns `int` (primitive), for which you don't need to collect into `Integer` i.e., it requires unnecessary boxing operation, so you can write as `int courseNumber = in.nextInt();`

Comment: Don't name it `Course`!

Comment: The assignment explicitly states that he cannot change the given file.